# Save post action in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to know whether a Wordpress plugin has an action to catch the event when a post and all its postmetadata is saved?

I use the `save_post` action, but then all its postmetadata is not yet saved. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I don't think WordPress automatically does that. You might need to use update_post_meta(). Have a look at this post: http://www.codetab.org/wordpress-plugin-development-tutorial/wordpress-save-post/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `added_post_meta` and `updated_post_meta` action hook, which are fired after the post meta data is saved.  Assuming that your meta data is saved after the post, of course:

```
add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'after_post_meta', 10, 4);
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'after_post_meta', 10, 4);

function after_post_meta( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
{
    // do stuff
}
```

You should have both action hooks in there, to make sure that you cover both ways of saving meta data: `add_metadata` and `update_metadata`.

If you're using a custom post type, you can change the action hook to reflect that.  For example, if you have a CPT of 'book':

```
add_action( 'added_book_meta', 'after_post_meta', 10, 4);
add_action( 'updated_book_meta', 'after_post_meta', 10, 4);
```